# Cant get ping to work in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ping

I'm having a problem using ping in a batch file.

I changed the directory to be the location of where the batch file is running from (typically in a folder on the desktop) using.....

```
set path=%cd%
```

Later in the batch file I use.....

```
set /a t=t+1
echo Pinging 192.168.1.%t%.........
ping -n 1 192.168.1.%t% | find "TTL"
if not errorlevel 1 goto nextaction
if errorlevel 1 goto down
```

I'm getting an error message that I cannot see even using pause after this command string or even writing the ping command to a log file.

I believe it is saying ping is not recognized.

I have tried

```
C:\windows\system32\ping -n 1 192.168.1.%t% | find "TTL"
```

Comment: `set path=%cd%` That is completely wrong; you now don't have all of the standard EXEs in `\Windows\System32`.  Don't do that.

Comment: Solved.....

    set /a t=t+1
    echo Pinging 192.168.1.%t%.........
    cd c:\windows\system32\
    ping -n 1 192.168.1.%t% | find "TTL"
    if not errorlevel 1 goto nextaction
    if errorlevel 1 goto down
    
    :nextaction
    cd %path%
    %whatever%

Comment: don't use `path` as a variable name. It is a systemvariable which tells where to find programs.

Comment: instead of saving `%cd%` take a look to those commands: `pushd` and `popd`